# Hartshorne Example IV.3.3.2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne states in Chapter IV:

> **Example 3.3.2.** Let $X$ be a curve, and let $D$ be a very ample divisor on $X$ corresponding to a closed immersion $\varphi\colon X \to \mathbb{P}^n$. Then the degree of $\varphi(X)$ is just equal to $\deg D$.

Why is this true?

Comment: If $H$ is a hyperplane in the projective space, do you know what $H\cap \phi(X)$ is?

Comment: The business with the Hilbert polynomial to define degree is a bit obscure, but surely at this point you have learned that you can compute the degree of $\varphi(X)$ by intersecting with a general linear subspace of complimentary dimension, yes?

Comment: @Mohan No, I don't.

Comment: This is an application of Bezout's theorem, **I Theorem 7.7** in Hartshorne (p.53).